# Updating String in a matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

I am having quite a bit of trouble updating a string using a push button in my created matlab GUI. The goal would be to have this button preform a function on an image, whose string has been placed in a textbox on the GUI, then replace the old string with the new image's string

The main issue that I have run into is that I need the file to be in .raw format, but I am unable to figure out how I would accomplish that. I can replace the old string with a new string in .png format with the following code by adding it the guide GUI code.

```
handles.currentImage = imread(get(handles.Textbox1,'string'));
handles.currentImage = Addnoise(handles.currentImage); %addnoise is the function i created. 
imwrite(handles.currentImage, 'photonoise', 'png');
pathname = 'C:\Documents and Settings\staff\My Documents\MATLAB\photonoise.png';
set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', fullfile(pathname));
```

But i am totally lost on how to make the string format a .raw. If there is some code I do not know about that i need to add to the GUI or to the Addnoise function, please let me know, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by a ".raw" format?  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, write an image to a textbox?

Comment: `imwrite` doesn't appear to support `.raw` images.  @macduff I believe that `.raw` is an image format that isn't compressed.

Comment: BTW, your title and actual problem don't really match.  I would suggest a rewrite of the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`.raw`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) images are not supported by [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), you won't be able to use it.  However, since `.raw` is a image format that isn't compressed this can be easily done using [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html).

Here's an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2VL72P/) using a 300 x 100 matrix of just zeroes (black):

```
cmodel=(zeros(300,100,1));
fid=fopen('blackimage.raw','w+');
cnt=fwrite(fid,cmodel,'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

so in your case you'll need to modify this to the following:

```
fid=fopen('myimage.raw','w+');
cnt=fwrite(fid,handles.currentImage,'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

<sup>Warning: my knowledge of the `.raw` format is pretty limited as well as `imread` so please take this with a grain (maybe even a cube) of salt</sup>